# Remove Chips from Vuetify Multi Select in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `vuetify v.2` and creating some `multi select` via `v-for`.
everything is ok except removing `chips`. When I try to remove form any `select`, it removes from the last one. It got something to do with `index` of removed `item` as defined in `remove` method. Looks like all `items` get `index` of the last `select`.

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
<v-row class="ma-0">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6" class="px-1" v-for="attribute in allAttr" :key="attribute.id">
        <v-select
            v-model="attrArr"
            :items="attribute.items"
            item-text="title"
            item-value="id"
            chips
            :label="attribute.title"
            multiple
            outlined
            @change="changed()"
        >
            <template v-slot:selection="{ attrs, item, select, selected }">
            <v-chip
                v-bind="attrs"
                :input-value="selected"
                close
                @click="select"
                @click:close="remove(item)"
            >
                <strong>{{ item.title }}</strong>
            </v-chip>
            </template>
        </v-select>
    </v-col>
    {{attrArr}}
</v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            attrArr:[],
            allAttr: null
        }
    },

    async fetch(){
        // fetch all attributes
        //this.allAttr = await this.axiosGet(`attributes/0/1`)
        this.allAttr = [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "color",
                items:[
                    {
                        id: 11,
                        title: "blue"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 12,
                        title: "green"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 13,
                        title: "black"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "size",
                items:[
                    {
                        id: 21,
                        title: "L"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 22,
                        title: "S"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: "Material",
                items:[
                    {
                        id: 31,
                        title: "X01"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 32,
                        title: "X02"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 33,
                        title: "X03"
                    },
                    {
                        id: 34,
                        title: "X04"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    methods: {
      remove (item) {
        this.attrArr.splice(this.attrArr.indexOf(item), 1)
        this.attrArr = [...this.attrArr]
      },
      changed(){
          this.$emit('changed', this.attrArr)
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just pass in the `id` instead of the entire `item` object...

```
 <v-chip
     v-bind="attrs"
     :input-value="selected"
     close
     @click="select"
     @click:close="remove(item.id)">
     <strong>{{ item.title }}</strong>
 </v-chip> 

 ...
 remove (id) {
    let idx = this.attrArr.indexOf(id)
    this.attrArr.splice(idx, 1)
    this.attrArr = [...this.attrArr]
 },
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/Cb5TYCS6Bt

Comment: I am having the same problem but with values selected by default. I want to say in a edition stage instead of creation,  If I remove the first item removes the next instead of selected...

Answer (score 1):

in your remove method you're looking for the index of an object within attrArr which consists of ids only. Try this instead:

```
this.attrArr.splice(this.attrArr.indexOf(item.id), 1)
```